# see logcats when device not connected to computer

Tags: android, debugging, widget, logcat

I use android widget. My widget working optimal for about 6 to 8 hours, after that error occurred. Is there a solution for see my application Logcat when error occur?(android device not connected to computer when error occur)

Comment: Dump the logs in a file. Pull the file later

Comment: use a file or show the error as a toast or as some activity with the detail or send it via sms or via email or something like that :)

Comment: Another solution: use [ACRA](http://www.acra.ch/), or any other crash report system.

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal Where is my logs ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a system of recording logs in a file on the device:
[stackoverflow.com/questions/11826025/log4j-implementation-in-android][1]

Or you can use:
  [firebase.google.com/docs/crash/][1]